# What is the structure of these sentences?

Tags: sentence-structure

- they can have an enjoyable time watching movies or playing video games together.
- let yourself fall asleep enjoying the safety found in silence.

why there isn't any linking word before "watching movies" and "enjoying" ?

Comment: Elaborate. What linking words you think there should be?

Comment: I mean a sentence like this : they can have an enjoyable time "while" watching movies or playing video games together.

Comment: If there is no ambiguity and "while" can be omitted, it most often will (https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/8-12.html#:~:text=Omitting%20when%2C%20while%20and%20upon&text=A%20prepositional%20phrase%20with%20when,action)%20in%20the%20main%20clause.&text=While%20or%20when%20can%20be,the%20modifying%20phrase%20refers%20to).

Comment: I understood. Thank you @fev

Comment: The first sentence shows more than mere synchronicity (I'm not sure how to interpret the second; it sounds like ad-bloviation). I'd say a decent paraphrase is 'they can enjoy themselves by watching movies or playing video games together' (although the 'session' implication has gone here). 'While' isn't the correct add-in here.

Comment: Having an enjoyable time watching movies is one thing. Having an enjoyable time while watching movies is another. The former implies passivity, while the latter implies the enjoyment is enhanced by doing other things while watching movies. An example of the latter is, say, talking about the movie while the movie is playing, or sampling different kinds of snacks. Again, the implication of the latter is that they are doing other things besides just watching the movie.

Comment: Grammatically, in both cases the gerund-participial clauses are functioning as depictive adjuncts in clause structure. Such non-finite clauses don't need a conjunction.

Comment: Those have reduced **adverb clauses**, reduced from: *They can have an enjoyable time **while they watch movies or play video games together**. Let yourself fall asleep **while you enjoy the safety found in silence**.* Remove *while* and the common subject, and change the verb to its present participle form.